# Neural Networks for Large Repetitive Sets of Inputs

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, supervised-learning

Suppose we want to make a neural network to predict the outcome of a race between some number of participants.

Each participant in the race has various statistics: Engine Power, Max Speed, Driver Experience, etc.

Now imagine we have been asked to build a system which can handle any number of participants from 2 to 400 participants (just to pick a concrete number).

From what I have learned about "traditional" Neural Nets so far, our choices are:

1. Build many different neural nets for each number of participants: n = 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , 400.
2. Train one neural network taking input from 400 participants. When a piece of data refers to a race with less that 400 participants (this will be a large percentage of the data) just set all remaining statistic inputs to 0.

Assuming this would work, is there any reason to expect one method to perform better than the other?

The former is more specialized, but you have much less training data per net, so my guess is that it would work out roughly the same?

Is there a standard way to approach problems similar to this?

We could imagine (simplistically) that the neural network first classifies the strength of each participant, and therefore, each time a new participant is added, it needs to apply this same analysis to these new inputs, potentially hinting that there might be a "smart" way to reduce the total amount of work required.

Is this just screaming for a convolutional neural network?

Comment: What does this topic have to do with programming or development? I think you should use another site on the Stack Exchange network for these questions. See [All Sites - Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) and maybe [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between your two options, option 1 would involve repeating a lot of effort to train for different sizes, and would probably be very slow to train as a result.

Option 2 is a bit more workable, but the network would need extra training on different sized inputs.

Another option, which I think would be the most likely to work, would be to only train a neural net to choose a winner between two participants, and use this to create a ranking via many comparisons between pairs. Such an approach is described [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f6a1/e14b600fc34b895c9fbcc07174a23af15657.pdf).

> We could imagine (simplistically) that the neural network first classifies the strength of each participant, and therefore, each time a new participant is added, it needs to apply this same analysis to these new inputs, potentially hinting that there might be a "smart" way to reduce the total amount of work required.

I think you've got the key idea here. Since we want to perform exactly the same analysis on each participants (assuming it makes no difference whether they're participant 1 or participant 400), this is an ideal problem for *Weight Sharing*. This means that the weights on the neurons doing the initial analysis on a participant are identical for each participant. When these weights change for one participant, they change for all participants.

While CNNs do use weight sharing, we don't need to use a CNN to use this technique. The details of how you'd go about doing this would depend on your framework.